# C: Array of structs in struct of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have these  structures:

```
struct menu_item{
    int id;
    char *text;
};

struct menu_tab{
    char *label;
    unsigned char item_count;
    struct menu_item *items;
};

struct menu_page{
    char *label;
    unsigned char tab_count;
    struct menu_tab *tabs;
};

struct Tmenu{
    unsigned char page_count;
    struct menu_page *pages;
};
```

And I would like to define the whole menu-system:

```
struct Tmenu menu_test = {
    2,
    {
        "F1",
        2,
        {
            {
                "File",
                8,
                {
                    {1, "text  1"},
                    {2, "text2"},
                    {3, "text3333333"},
                    {4, "text4"},
                    {5, "Hello"},
                    {6, "42"},
                    {7, "world"},
                    {8, "!!!!!!!!"}
                }

            },
            {
                "File2",
                3,
                {
                    {11, "file2 text  1"},
                    {12, "blah"},
                    {13, "..."}
                }

            }
        }
    },
    {
        "F2",
        1,
        {
            {
                "File3",
                5,
                {
                    {151, "The Answer To Life"},
                    {152, "The Universe"},
                    {153, "and everything"},
                    {154, "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiis"},
                    {42, "Fourty-Two"}
                }

            }
        }
    }
};
```

But when I try to compile, I get  `extra brace group at end of initializer` error messages.

I tried many different ways to do it, but none of them succeeded. So is it possible at all to use complex structures in C, like this?

Comment: Did you just come from PHP? :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, this usage is not possible, at least not in "old" (C89) C. A struct literal cannot be used to initialize a *pointer* to the structure in question, since that doesn't solve the question of where in memory the struct is located.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Tmenu menu_test = {
    2,
    {
        "F1",
        2,
        {DATAFILE...},
        {DATAFILE2...}
    },
```

Should be

```
struct Tmenu menu_test = {
    2,
    {
        "F1",
        2,
        {
        {DATAFILE...},
        {DATAFILE2...}
        }
    },
```

because the array of struct will loose the declaration for single braces.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you declared a pointer to a struct, but in fact you want an array of structs. Most of time `struct name*` and `struct name[]` will be "interchangeable" ( Read K&R to see that they are not the same thing), but in case of static initialization it must be declared as an array so the compiler can expected it to be of fixed size and therefore it can determine the amount of memory to be used  for the struct.

I need to improve my answer,but my main point here is that I would not expect something  like `int a* = {3,3,4,5};` to compile. First the type is different on both sides of the assignment. Second how can the compiler know it is an initialization list for an array and not an struct? Third, how can it know that it should expect 4 elements and not 5?

Comment: Perhaps you should change to `struct struct_name[3] = {{init-list for 1},{init-list for 2},{init-list for 3}};` Then the compiler know it must expect 3 structs. If you cant fix the number of structs, then you have to break the initialization in other minor initializations and set the pointers among them.