# how to initialize nested arrays

Tags: c

What is the correct syntax to initialize the following 2 level of nested arrays ?

```
z3 src # cat tc.c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct level1_t {
        char                           var[15];
        int                            value;
} level1_t;

typedef struct level2_t {
    level1_t     data[3];
} level2_t;

level2_t level2[1] = {
                [0]={
                        [0]={"one",1},
                        [1]={"two",2},
                        [2]={"three",3}
                }
};

int main() {

        printf("%s\n",level2[0].data[1].var);
}
z3 src # gcc -ggdb -o tc tc.c
tc.c:14:4: error: array index in non-array initializer
tc.c:14:4: error: (near initialization for 'level2[0]')
tc.c:15:4: error: array index in non-array initializer
tc.c:15:4: error: (near initialization for 'level2[0]')
tc.c:15:4: error: extra brace group at end of initializer
tc.c:15:4: error: (near initialization for 'level2[0]')
tc.c:15:4: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
tc.c:15:4: warning: (near initialization for 'level2[0]')
tc.c:16:4: error: array index in non-array initializer
tc.c:16:4: error: (near initialization for 'level2[0]')
tc.c:16:4: error: extra brace group at end of initializer
tc.c:16:4: error: (near initialization for 'level2[0]')
tc.c:16:4: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
tc.c:16:4: warning: (near initialization for 'level2[0]')
z3 src #
```

Comment: Just as a warning, this syntax is only available in C ISO C99 (not C++).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
level2_t level2[1] = {
                [0]={
                        [0]={"one",1},
                        [1]={"two",2},
                        [2]={"three",3}
                }
};
```

to

```
level2_t level2[1] = {
                [0].data = {
                        [0]={"one",1},
                        [1]={"two",2},
                        [2]={"three",3}
                }
};
```

Right now you're trying to initialize the structure as an array, while you need to initialize the `data` field.

As you asked in comments here's how to do the same thing without indexes:

```
level2_t level2[] = {
    {
        .data = {
            {"one", 1},
            {"two", 2},
            {"three", 3}
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: by any chance do you know what would be the syntax without the square brackets [0],[1],[2] at all ?

Answer (score 0):

```
level2_t level2 =
{
   {"one, 1},
   {"two, 2},
   {"three", 3}
};
```

Comment: This is a better way of initializing the entire data structure, as it is more portable.

Comment: yes, but it doesn't detail the nesting, also it misses fixed size of the array, what if I make a syntax error and initalize larger structure than I should?